# AWS Lambda targerting CloudWatch Logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I tried to follow [Using DynamoDB with Custom Alexa Skills - Dabble Lab #226 - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YDqKUobjw3E&t=295s&ab_channel=DabbleLab) video, had some issues that mostly I was able to fix. I guess I am just to new to AWS and Lambda. But I wonder if someone is able to explain me why I don't have CloudWatch Logs as target, as shown in the video and how I can fix that. When I try to save a movietitle alexa sais 'we cannot save your movie right now. Try again!'. Would be amazing If someone here could help me : )

[image]

My lambda code:

```
/* eslint-disable  func-names */
/* eslint-disable  no-console */

const Alexa = require('ask-sdk');
const dbHelper = require('./helpers/dbHelper');
const GENERAL_REPROMPT = "What would you like to do?";
const dynamoDBTableName = "dynamodb-starter";
const LaunchRequestHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'LaunchRequest';
  },
  handle(handlerInput) {
    const speechText = 'Hello there. What is your favourite movie? You can say add moviename to add your favourite movie or say list my movies to get your favourite movies.';
    const repromptText = 'What would you like to do? You can say HELP to get available options';

    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak(speechText)
      .reprompt(repromptText)
      .getResponse();
  },
};

const InProgressAddMovieIntentHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;
    return request.type === 'IntentRequest' &&
      request.intent.name === 'AddMovieIntent' &&
      request.dialogState !== 'COMPLETED';
  },
  handle(handlerInput) {
    const currentIntent = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent;
    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .addDelegateDirective(currentIntent)
      .getResponse();
  }
}

const AddMovieIntentHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest'
      && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'AddMovieIntent';
  },
  async handle(handlerInput) {
    const {responseBuilder } = handlerInput;
    const userID = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.context.System.user.userId; 
    const slots = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots;
    const movieName = slots.MovieName.value;
    return dbHelper.addMovie(movieName, userID)
      .then((data) => {
        const speechText = `You have added movie ${movieName}. You can say add to add another one or remove to remove movie`;
        return responseBuilder
          .speak(speechText)
          .reprompt(GENERAL_REPROMPT)
          .getResponse();
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log("Error occured while saving movie", err);
        const speechText = "we cannot save your movie right now. Try again!"
        return responseBuilder
          .speak(speechText)
          .getResponse();
      })
  },
};

const GetMoviesIntentHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest'
      && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'GetMoviesIntent';
  },
  async handle(handlerInput) {
    const {responseBuilder } = handlerInput;
    const userID = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.context.System.user.userId; 
    return dbHelper.getMovies(userID)
      .then((data) => {
        var speechText = "Your movies are "
        if (data.length == 0) {
          speechText = "You do not have any favourite movie yet, add movie by saving add moviename "
        } else {
          speechText += data.map(e => e.movieTitle).join(", ")
        }
        return responseBuilder
          .speak(speechText)
          .reprompt(GENERAL_REPROMPT)
          .getResponse();
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        const speechText = "we cannot get your movie right now. Try again!"
        return responseBuilder
          .speak(speechText)
          .getResponse();
      })
  }
}

const InProgressRemoveMovieIntentHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;
    return request.type === 'IntentRequest' &&
      request.intent.name === 'RemoveMovieIntent' &&
      request.dialogState !== 'COMPLETED';
  },
  handle(handlerInput) {
    const currentIntent = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent;
    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .addDelegateDirective(currentIntent)
      .getResponse();
  }
}

const RemoveMovieIntentHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest'
      && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'RemoveMovieIntent';
  }, 
  handle(handlerInput) {
    const {responseBuilder } = handlerInput;
    const userID = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.context.System.user.userId; 
    const slots = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots;
    const movieName = slots.MovieName.value;
    return dbHelper.removeMovie(movieName, userID)
      .then((data) => {
        const speechText = `You have removed movie with name ${movieName}, you can add another one by saying add`
        return responseBuilder
          .speak(speechText)
          .reprompt(GENERAL_REPROMPT)
          .getResponse();
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        const speechText = `You do not have movie with name ${movieName}, you can add it by saying add`
        return responseBuilder
          .speak(speechText)
          .reprompt(GENERAL_REPROMPT)
          .getResponse();
      })
  }
}

const HelpIntentHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest'
      && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'AMAZON.HelpIntent';
  },
  handle(handlerInput) {
    const speechText = 'You can introduce yourself by telling me your name';

    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak(speechText)
      .reprompt(speechText)
      .getResponse();
  },
};

const CancelAndStopIntentHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest'
      && (handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'AMAZON.CancelIntent'
        || handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'AMAZON.StopIntent');
  },
  handle(handlerInput) {
    const speechText = 'Goodbye!';

    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak(speechText)
      .getResponse();
  },
};

const SessionEndedRequestHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'SessionEndedRequest';
  },
  handle(handlerInput) {
    console.log(`Session ended with reason: ${handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.reason}`);

    return handlerInput.responseBuilder.getResponse();
  },
};

const ErrorHandler = {
  canHandle() {
    return true;
  },
  handle(handlerInput, error) {
    console.log(`Error handled: ${error.message}`);

    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak('Sorry, I can\'t understand the command. Please say again.')
      .reprompt('Sorry, I can\'t understand the command. Please say again.')
      .getResponse();
  },
};

const skillBuilder = Alexa.SkillBuilders.standard();

exports.handler = skillBuilder
  .addRequestHandlers(
    LaunchRequestHandler,
    InProgressAddMovieIntentHandler,
    AddMovieIntentHandler,
    GetMoviesIntentHandler,
    InProgressRemoveMovieIntentHandler,
    RemoveMovieIntentHandler,
    HelpIntentHandler,
    CancelAndStopIntentHandler,
    SessionEndedRequestHandler
  )
  .addErrorHandlers(ErrorHandler)
  .withTableName(dynamoDBTableName)
  .withAutoCreateTable(true)
  .lambda();
```

The code when deployed:

```
lucasfalkowsky@Lucass-MacBook-Pro kneipe-temp % ask deploy -p ______
Deploy configuration loaded from ask-resources.json
Deploy project for profile [____]

==================== Deploy Skill Metadata ====================
[Warn]: The hash of current skill package folder does not change compared to the last deploy hash result, CLI will skip the deploy of skill package.
Skill ID: ___________

==================== Build Skill Code ====================
npm WARN dynamodb-starter@1.0.0 No repository field.

audited 18 packages in 1.094s
found 0 vulnerabilities

Skill code built successfully.
Code for region default built to /Users/___/Desktop/___/___/___/___/___/.ask/lambda/custom/build.zip successfully with build flow NodeJsNpmBuildFlow.

==================== Deploy Skill Infrastructure ====================
  ✔ Deploy Alexa skill infrastructure for region "default"
Skill infrastructures deployed successfully through @ask-cli/lambda-deployer.

==================== Enable Skill ====================
Skill is already enabled, skip the enable process.
```

The [Original Project](https://github.com/dabblelab/10-alexa-dynamodb-datastore-example-skill) on Git Hub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand you are missing the lambda logs in cloudwatch. So for them to enable you need to have an IAM Role with managed  polciy [AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-intro-execution-role.html).

That gives following permissions to  lambda to log to cloudwatch:

```
        {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": [
                    "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                    "logs:CreateLogStream",
                    "logs:PutLogEvents"
                ],
                "Resource": "*"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: I already did that and redeployed. Seems to be a different issue. But thanks ;) Do you have some other ideas?

Comment: are you sure your lambda iam role has this permission if yes, then your lambda must not have been executed yet. So double check both of them, you can manually trigger the lambda as well from the console/cli .

Comment: I added the picture of my role to youre answer. as you see in CloudWatchLogs there are the settings you described. I know its german ^^sorry

Comment: just suggestion , please dont share your account details on public platform and for sharing information you can add them in comments. Yes I can see that , can you try execution the lambda manually from the console and if there is any error, you can share the same here.

Comment: Is the arn to be kept secret?

Comment: yes, that contains your account id. I can help you with all your questions you can reach me here https://www.linkedin.com/in/vgsuresh/. This would be good for you, otherwise, I can see you can pay some heavy penalties for exposing those details on the internet.

Comment: There is no error. I can start the alexa skill but can not use a command for adding data to the database. The Lambda function hast full access to dynamodb so that is not the issue. But As I said the CloudWatch Logs are not as target.

Comment: so when you say CloudWatch Logs are not as target do you mean you can not see logs in the cloudwatch ? because this is what I am assuming while I am trying to answer and if possible can you share the error message when you tried to execute the lambda manually from the console?

Comment: There is no error when I make a test function to start the application. that works. There is a problem when I want to use the add 'string' to the database command. It is hard to figure this out over text. At least for me ^^sorry for that. I added a picture of what I mean at the top.

Comment: picture is not helping at all, can you share the code you have deployed ?

Comment: that too won't help because this is infra code which is deployed and having trouble. So what you can do, share the full  logs when you deployed with command used.

Comment: I added the output that is displayed when deploying.

Comment: did you check if the IAM role for lambda has [trust policy assigned](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-intro-execution-role.html#permissions-executionrole-api) ? plus is it possible for you to share full repository for this project that includes the infrastructure code as well.

Comment: would you like me to share the project via git or does stackoverflow have a service for that?

Comment: yeah, I think sharing the code via github would be good but before that make sure all the credentials are cleaned from it. What I see from your post you are using some kind of pre baked projects provided by Dabble Lab, so they must be making it available somewhere on github, you can share the same.

Comment: Alright I added the original Project for Git Hub ab the bottom of my Question. By the way, thank you for sticking with me for this long ;)

Comment: as per the code you have attached you just have attach the DyanmoDB permissions. But in the image earlier you showed there were 4 permissions. One seems like was a custom policy. Can you remove others and keep only the ones provided in the doc and try.

Comment: Ok now I just added the permissions shown by dabble Lab. AWSBasicExecutionRole and DynamodbFullAcess. I still can start the Skill but when executing add (moviename) it gives the error defined in the lambda function in AddMovieIntentHandler saying "we cannot save your movie right now. Try again!". That shows me, that there was an error saving the movie -> may have no access to the database

Comment: that just saying you dont have necessary permissions to add items to the DB as per the [code](https://github.com/dabblelab/10-alexa-dynamodb-datastore-example-skill/blob/bdcff5efc55baddd672de5282a3405623e5983ab/lambda/custom/helpers/dbHelper.js#L8). Are you able to see the logs now ?

Comment: I can visit the logGroup of my lambda function. The target is still not displayed in the Lambda configuration tab.

Comment: I can't continue this discussion here because it is getting un-necessary long and it's just plain debugging here. as I suggested earlier you can reach out to me on Linkedin and I can help you.

Comment: Alright. Thank you for the ambition. I hope to get in contact with the writer of the basecode. He should know this the best. Have a nice Day ;)